# XSLT not working now I added a namespace

Tags: xslt

I just added a namespace to my XML document and now my XSLT stylesheet does not work.  What do I have to change in XSLT to support namespaces?  (I have not yet changed the XSLT file since adding namespaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `xmlns:namespacehere` attribute and use the namespace in the appropriate matches and selections.

Comment: While this answer is correct, do note that `xmlns:namespacehere` is not an attribute -- it is a namespace declaration that defines a namespace node.